# Consuming a WCF REST service from Android is very slow

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, rest, binary

I have a WCF REST service built with C# and it returns an image as part of a CPU intensive operation. The client is running on Android (Java) By default, it will return a text JSON object that looks something like this:

{"d",[9,0,77,12,11,...]}

Those are they bytes of the image.  Fine.  However, all the solutions for decoding this JSON are intolerably slow.  I've tried Gson, Jackson, and the built-in Android JSONObject class.  I have no idea why they are so slow.

As an alternative solution, I have my REST service return a GUID, and then that GUID can be used by the Android client to go to a regular URL that serves up the image as a regular binary stream, via an MVC controller.

This works well, and it fast, and is pretty easy to handle on the Android side.  However, it does feel like a bit of kludge and kind of a violation of the REST design principles.

Am I missing something here?  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about your REST service return a Redirect 303 with a Location header that has an URL that points to the image?  Or why not just return the bytes directly from the first URL?

As far as RESTful or not, returning a JSON encoded image is not exactly in the spirit of the REST self-descriptive constraint.

Just make sure the endpoint that returns the image stream of bytes, actually uses an image/* media type in the content header.

Comment: Using WCF, you are restricted to returning JSON or XML

Comment: No, that is not true.  I have a WCF service that I return a dozen different media types from.  Use Stream as your method return type and you can return anything.

Comment: Hmm.  I was looking at:

 [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]

That only gives you XML or Json.

However, if you use:

WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/xml"

It looks like you can return any type.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, on of your main problems is trying to transmit binary data using a text format.
Most if not all java json libraries will try to recognize the type of the field.  It'll take a long time if there's a lot of fields.

Yeah, streaming it directly is a lot faster.  Maybe you can use XML since it supports binary or blob data.

Answer (score 0):

As Darrel wrote above, if the URL computes and returns an Image, simply return that Image with an appropriate content-type, for e.g., as a PNG image. Transmitting the image encoded within JSON is a strange choice, to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great talk about developing rest client application on android form Google IO 2010.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE

> This session will present architectural considerations for developing RESTful applications on the Android platform. It focuses on design patterns, platform integration and performance issues specific to the Android platform.

A great resource and must watch.